# Azure VM - Re-deploying VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, redeploy

I'm a beginner in the Azure platform. I encountered a problem with a VM in my Company's Azure infrastructure, the VM wouldn't **start** after I *restarted it from OS*, I tried all other troubleshooting Features and was left with the `redeploy` option.

I wanted to be sure, that after the operation, the `network/domain` configuration will not be altered or changed, or even worse lost.

Answer (score 0):

From the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/redeploy-to-new-node):

> When you redeploy a VM, it moves the VM to a new node within the Azure
>   infrastructure and then powers it back on, retaining all your
>   configuration options and associated resources.

And

> After you redeploy a VM, the temporary disk is lost and dynamic IP
>   addresses associated with virtual network interface are updated.

So I would say you are safe to redeploy it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer !

Comment: No problem, please mark it as an answer if it helped, thanks :)